# iPhone Submit application on AppStore having Encryption

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, app-store

I am using AES256 CommonCrypto framework of iOS to encypt data in my application, application is client server communication, all the data is encypt and decrypt both ends, my question is that do I have to answer 'YES' or 'No' for Does application contains encryption on AppStore and I have to pass all the CCATS process for this according to Apple export? this is Apple own licensed framework, the domain is on http.

Also when I use https self-signed certificate, In that case answer 'YES' or 'No' for AppStore and has to pass the full process? and if I use trusted certificate my own. what about in that case?

Is is taking long process to pass the CCAT export law, can we submit the application without this?

I am not getting any satisfied answer on this anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: What did you do to solve this?